# How can I put an element of a string in a list with a certain behaviour

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list1 =  ['A', 'B']
list2 = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]]
```

I need my output as:

```
[[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)],[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]]
```

Now if I know that:

- length of sublist1 = 4
- length of sublist2 = 4

then how can I put all this in a dictionary like:

```
{'A':length of sublist1, 'B':length of sublist2}
```

Comment: Look at `split()`, list comprehensions, `len()`, and the `dict` constructor.

Comment: What exactly is the rule to determine how to group the items in the string? If there's 12 pairs instead of 8, would it be two lists of 6 or 3 of 4? Or is it chopping it into enough chunks to use with list1?

Comment: if the first element of 1,1 or 1,2  is 1 then it should be kept in sublist1 otherwise if the first element of 2,1 or 2,2 or 2,3 is 2 then it should be kept in sublist2.

Comment: Why do you have a list inside another list? (`list2 = [[...]]`)

Comment: becoz that is what I need to do. I need to do exactly the way I specified in the question that I have edited

Answer (score 4):

Using split and groupby:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data = [map(int, (z for z in x.split(','))) for x in string1.split()]
>>> a, b = [list(j) for j in groupby(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))]
>>> a
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
>>> b
[[2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> dict(zip(list1, (len(i) for i in (a,b))))
{'A': 4, 'B': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of lists as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
for val in string1.split():
    v1, v2 = val.split(',')
    data[v1].append(v2)
result = [[(int(key), int(v)) for v in values] for key, values in data.items()]
```

To get the dictionary you can do:

```
d = dict(zip(list1, result))
```

This gives you a list with the elements of `list1` as keys. To get the lengths you can do:

```
d = dict([(key, len(ls)) for key, ls in zip(list1, result)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to play with your data a bit to reduce to how you want it. Like the first section below demonstrates and then you will have to create a dictionary and then look for the values in the dict. Here is the code for your sample data. You should be abel to build up on that.

```
>>> string1 = '1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,1 2,2 2,3 2,4'
>>> list1 = string1.split(',')
>>> list2 = [tuple(map(int, a.split(','))) for a in list1]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]

>>> temp_dict = {}
>>> for each in list2:
...     a = each[0]
...     if a in temp_dict:
...             temp_dict[a].append(each)
...     else:
...             temp_dict[a] = [each]
... 
>>> temp_dict.values()
[[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)], [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]]
```

Comment: if I am getting an output like [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]] then how should I split this like the one u showed?

Answer (score 0):

Take your list of tuples and split it into separate lists based on the first number in each tuple. In the same step, add the filtered list to the dictionary with the corresponding key from `list1`. Because of the double brackets in `list2` (copied below), the actual data is in `list2[0]`.

```
//note the double brackets, data is in list2[0], not list2
list2 = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]]

d = dict()

for i in range (0, len(list1)):
     d[list1[i]] = [x for x in list2[0] if x[0] == i+1]
     //on the first run though, list[i] will be 'A' and will be set to [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
     //on the 2nd run though, list[i] will be 'B' and will be set to [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Printing `d` shows the formatted data

```
print(d)
//prints {'A': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)], 'B': [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]}
```

EDIT: I misread the question (I thought you wanted the actual data in the dictionary, not just the lengths). To get the length of the list instead of the contents, just wrap the second list comprehension in a `len()` like

```
len([x for x in list2[0] if x[0] == i+1])
```

After that change, `d` will contain the lengths, not the data:

```
print(d) //{'A': 4, 'B': 4}
```