# How to get the count of tuples from a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put an element of a string in a list with a certain behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726305/how-can-i-put-an-element-of-a-string-in-a-list-with-a-certain-behaviour)

Suppose I have two lists:

```
list1 = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]]

list2 = ['A']
```

Now I need something like

```
dic1 = {'A': len(list1)}
```

Now `len(list1)` should be `4` as I need to count the number of tuples which in this case is 4.

Comment: It looks like list1 contains 1 list, whose length is 4. The length of list1 should be 1.

Comment: Could you not get this from your previous question and answers?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726305/how-can-i-put-an-element-of-a-string-in-a-list-with-a-certain-behaviour

Answer (score 1):

`dic1 = {'A': len(list1[0])}`

Right now you are getting the length of `list1`, but `list1` is a list with another list in it. Using this, you are accessing the list of tuples inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
dic1 = {list2[0]: len(list1[0])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some wild guessing on what you are actually trying to do:

```
>>> list1 = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)], [(2, 1), (2, 2)]]
>>> list2 = ['A', 'B']
>>> dic1 = {key: len(tuples) for (key, tuples) in zip(list2, list1)}
>>> dic1
{'A': 4, 'B': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `list1` only has one item - another list. What you're trying to get is the length of the list in `list1`.

So use `len(list1[0])` instead of `len(list1)` and you should be good.